# How to charge a battery model by sun irradiance model?

Tags: matlab, simulink, modeling

I am new at modeling. I created a mathematical model via some equations to calculate sun irradiance. The last function does it but I couldn't connect the output (pin) to the battery to charge. What should I do ? Heard just that I needed to add a powergui block.

Note :

Before roast me, I know nothing about electricty !

[image]

Comment: You may need this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simulinkpsconverter.html
The battery is part of the Simscape package, which works with 'physical' signals, different to the 'normal' signals of simulink

Comment: thanks for your comment but it doesn't work even though I tried it